# App for calling a list of contacts, one after another

Tags: applications, calls

My daily commute is rather long, and I make lots of phone calls while driving. Dialing while driving is illegal, so I have to stop by, dial, and drive again, which is inefficient, time consuming and unsafe.

Is there a way to create a list of contacts in advance, so that my Android will dial all the contacts on the list one after another?

Comment: What about using Voice Dialling via a bluetooth headset? Is that considered against the law in your location?

Comment: It is not illegal, but voice recognition in Hebrew is nonexistent or poor. Moreover, it requires action on my part and distracts my attention from driving.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't dial automatically, you can add contacts to your home screen for one click dialing.

Home Screen > Menu > Add > Shortcuts > Direct Dial

Now choose a contact.

You'll now have an icon on your home screen that will dial with one click. Do that for all of your contacts and you can have a homescreen of contacts.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but the contacts are not always the same, and clicking a contact still requires some attention.

Comment: Not a good idea, but seems the only current solution. putting big number of contacts on home screen, and sorting them each time is hard.